# What's the Bermudian equivalent of USA's W-2 form or Canada's T4?

Tags: income-tax, income-statement

What can be used as a proof of income, for someone who was born, lives and works in Bermuda?  I'm looking for the most official, widely-accepted, and least-manipulatable document.

Answer (score 1):

Self-employed individuals and employers [must file payroll taxes quarterly](http://www.gov.bm/portal/server.pt?open=512&objID=275&&PageID=231418&mode=2&in_hi_userid=2&cached=true).  These documents would serve as proof of income I would think.

Comment: What about for a plain employee?  Would they typically receive a copy of the payroll taxes documentation filed on their behalf by their employer?

Comment: If not, they can ask for them, I'd think. :)